# The ratio of cooper pairs and normal electrons in superconducting state

Tags: superconductivity

Is there a certain ratio between cooper pairs and normal electrons above which the sample can be said to be in a superconducting state? According to the Ginzburg-Landau theory the sample is in a superconducting state when the order parameter is above zero, but this is hard to realize in practise. Is there more developed model to define the superconducting state? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Hi @Light.  I think you may need to refine your question a bit.  If you have a sample where Cooper pairs have begun to form, it is in the superconducting state.   You cannot have Cooper pairs and still be in the normal state.  So there is no ratio to define.

Comment: So if I would be just below the transition temperature where the order parameter is just barely above zero, which meas that there are only few cooper pairs present, am I then in a superconducting state? Surely the critical current is not even measurable.

Comment: I don't know that it makes sense to think about only a few Cooper pairs.  Once the gap forms at the Fermi surface, you will have already many, many Cooper pairs.  To my mind, it is like ice taken to its melt point.  Many molecules enter the liquid state at essentially the same time.  Could one measure the viscosity of those in the liquid state at that point (which would last a very short time)?  Not likely.  If you don't mind, can I ask what you ultimately want to understand?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ultimately wan to understand the order parameter in the GL-theory. In the case of type-II superconductors, where vortices are present, the orderparameter can vary substantially from 1 and even  go to absolute 0 at the center of vortices. This it is problematic to define the areas where the sample is and is not a superconductor.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I am not well versed in GL theory, but I would say that if you re-write your question, it would be good to note that your main interest is in Type II superconductors and their associated vortex structure.  Good luck!